# Loop through while(sqlite3_step(statement) until all the rows

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I am storing multiple values in Sqlite database in my iOS app.

I need to retrieve the values under "cellForRowAtIndexPath"

```
- (NSString *) retrieveDetailText :(NSString *) emailAddress :(NSString *) uidText  :(NSString *) folderName {

    NSString *detailText = nil;

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    //SQLIte Statement
    NSString *selettablequery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from MailFolderDBTable"];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_prepare(database, [selettablequery UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) ==SQLITE_OK)
        {
            while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                char *uidfield = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5);
                NSString *uidStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: uidfield];
                NSLog(@"retrieveDetailText: uidStr: %@", uidStr);

                if([uidStr isEqualToString:uidText]) {

                    char *emailstring = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6);
                    NSString *detailTextData = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String: emailstring];

                    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:detailTextData options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];
                    detailText = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];

                }
```

From this code, I need to loop through at `while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)`

As I am calling `retrieveDetailText` under `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and it is not looping through here `while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)`, It checks `if([uidStr isEqualToString:uidText])` only one time.

How can i loop through `while(sqlite3_step(statement)` until all the rows checked and get the value.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need one row which satisfies `uidText`, then you can change your query no?

```
//SQLIte Statement
NSString *selettablequery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from MailFolderDBTable where uid = %@", uidText];
```

Otherwise, you can fetch all the data before loading your tableView, in an array and then use it as your tableView data source.

Comment: My question is different. And, this command is also not executing

Comment: @user1953977 Did you change column name to yours from "uid"?

Comment: "uid" is my column name as well. const char *sql_stmt = "create table if not exists MailFolderDBTable (emailid text, foldername text, messagedata text, totalmessages int, folderlist text, uid text, detailtext text)";